# How to access a cell value when the column has been defined with ag-grid value getters?

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

If the ag-grid column definition has been defined with a value getter , the value gets displayed fine on the grid. However I was not able to find a way to access a value in a given cell if the cell is using cell value getters. Was trying to access the data through api.forEachNode, but it doesnt show the data. The only way I found was to export the data as CSV and then parse it using getDataAsCsv(params).

Is exporting the data the only way to access value of a column in a grid with a value getter?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Good story, any code? or batter some demo: You can use this template: http://plnkr.co/edit/qk6pBtNQXEPj2Riy?preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add a new property to your data.

Let's say I have a derived column to show the row index, where I am just returning row index.

Before returning from value getter, I can add this index to a new property called 'special'

```
{
   headerName: 'Special',
   maxWidth: 100,
   valueGetter: function(params) {
    params.node.data.special = params.node.rowIndex; // added property called special
    return params.node.rowIndex;
   }  
},
```

You can now access this in api.forEachNode by doing -

```
this.gridApi.forEachNode(function(rowNode, index) {
     console.log(rowNode.data.special);
}
```

Comment: In this way i can fetch valuegetter values seperately.What if i want the entire grid data along with value getters.
To fetch entire grid data i use,
griddata=[]
this.gridApi.forEachNode((a)=>{
this.griddata.push(a.data)
console.log(this.griddata)

Here I am able access the entire grid values as json(field and value).But the field getting value through valueGetter is not fetched.
Kindly help @Pratik

Comment: if you look at the answer, you just need to create a new property in all of your value getters. The answer clearly states how you can access all your data inside api.foEachNode in rowNode.data. where do you think you have to access separately?